# Is there an EE addon for bulk status change from the entry edit screen?

Tags: status, bulk, batch-update, moderation

I'm creating a site with a moderation process that requires all new entries in a certain channel to be saved in draft status, and then an admin or editors will approve those entries and update the status to open.

There could be tens or hundreds of entries to approve at a time. Even with the native batch editing feature you still have a click on the select box for each entry and change the status.

What I really need is something that would allow me to select each draft entry I want to publish and then use a bulk status change action to change them to "open" all at once.

Is there an existing extension that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu should work for you, it has the ability to change statuses for batches of entries

Comment: If I understand the screenshots correctly, you still need to change the status select box for each single entry though, right? Does it allow for simply selecting a large number of entries via checkbox and then changing their status with one action?

Comment: It's been a while since I used Zenbu but it does have the facility for selecting a number of entries and updating status in one go - see http://zenbustudio.com/software/zenbu > Feature list > Improved multi-entry editor.

If you need clarification I'd suggest dropping them and email to confirm it!

Comment: @Benek Yes, a single select field in Zenbu is available in the multi-entry editor to change the status of multiple entries at once. Here's a screenshot for an example: http://cl.ly/image/0G3Q0D0T2X1d

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to spend money on an add-on just for this purpose, I found a bit of an inelegant solution.

I recently had to change the Status of hundreds of entries and used [Ben Alman's bookmarklet tool](http://benalman.com/code/test/jquery-run-code-bookmarklet/) to make things a little easier. It allowed me to run a small bit of jQuery on EE's Multi Entry Editor page and set each entry's Entry Status select dropdown to Closed:

- Enter a Bookmarklet name - "Set EE Status to Closed".
- Paste in jQuery code that will target all Entry Status select dropdowns:

```
$("table.mainTable select option[value='closed']").attr("selected","selected");
```

- Click the Generate button then drag the green bookmarklet button to your bookmark bar.
- On the EE Edit page I had to set the results dropdown to the max 150 results.
- Filter your entries however you need to then click the select all entries checkbox.
- Click Submit (obviously with 'Edit Selected' not 'Delete Selected') to access the Multi Entry Editor.
- Click your "Set EE Status to Closed" bookmarklet - all Entry Status dropdowns should be set to Closed